# Tumblr API Posting A Photo from HTML Canvas

Tags: php, html, api, canvas, tumblr

I'm having some issues trying to get my code to post the HTML canvas into Tumblr as a photo. I'm using PHP, and the code on the server side is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['postphoto']) and $_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $caption = $_POST['caption'];
    tags = $_POST['tags'];
    $imageData = $_POST['imageData'];
    $imageData = substr($imageData,strpos($imageData,",")+1);
    $imageData = str_replace(' ','+',$imageData);

    # Set access token
    $tumblr->set_token($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

    $data = array();
    $data['post'] = array(
        'type'   => 'photo',
        'generator' => 'AppName',
        'data'    => $imageData,
        'name'   => $title,
        'caption' => $caption,
        'tags' => $tags
    );

    $response = $tumblr->fetch('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write', $data);

    if($response['successful']) {
        echo "Update successful!<br><br>";
    } else {
       echo "Update failed. {$response[body]}<br><br>";
    }
}
```

On the JavaScript side, I have the following:

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");            
$("#imageData").val(imgData);
```

imageData is of form type hidden so I simply set the value. The entire form is then posted to the PHP side. I have checked and the values are passed correctly (I did a similar thing for TwitPic, it works since it simply takes in the toDataURL value, but Tumblr is giving lots of issue).

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Stupid question: are you using enctype="multipart-formdata"?

Comment: Hi Paddy! Tried with it and it doesn't work (and shouldn't matter, since the base64 encoded data is treated as a string when passed). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I have no idea if you're wrong or not. I just thought it was worth checking to make sure the facepalm solution wasn't the right one. :P

What issues is Tumblr giving? Have you tried just downloading the image first, to make sure that's working as expected? Tried downloading the image from the PHP script, to make sure that's working too?

Comment: Hi Paddy, the base64 data works just fine since I am using a near-identical solution for posting to TwitPic and it works. The issue is I've no idea what kind of data Tumblr wants (even from the API), haha.

Comment: In the end I solved this issue by having PHP write the dataURL (base64) to a temp image file first, and then submit that image file as a source (instead of data, see Tumblr api).

Comment: Tumblr wants "(URL-encoded binary contents)" as the data type.  I've been struggling with it all day =/

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are posting title to photo posts?
Photo posts don't have title. Let me know if it works when u remove  `'name'   => $title,`.